# Show value of textboxes in the select

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show the value of the textboxes in the select. For example, if you type anything in the `Chairperson`, `President` or `VicePresident` textfields the value of those textboxes should be displayed separately as options in the `select`.

I tried the below but it doesn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Chairperson_change").change(function() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown_change").value = document.getElementById("Signatories").value;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Chairperson: <input name="Chairperson" type="text" maxlength="50" id="Chairperson_change" style="width: 665px; padding:0px; z-index: 2; position: absolute;" /><br> 
President: <input name="President" type="text" maxlength="50" style="width: 665px; padding:0px; z-index: 2; position: absolute;"
/><br> 
VicePresident: <input name="VicePresident" type="text" maxlength="50" style="width: 665px; padding:0px; z-index: 2; position: absolute;" /><br>

<select id="dropdown_change"><br>
  <option value="">Options here</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with this question, can the person who downvote explain, what is the problem in the explanation, please?

Comment: Indeed. There is nothing wrong with this question at all, and the intent is obvious so I'm not sure why someone voted to close it as unclear either

Comment: You are setting the value of the dropdown to the value of `document.getElementById("Signatories").value` but where is `Signatories`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can hook to the `input` event of the textboxes. Then you can create new `option` elements for each textbox (based on its `id`), or update one if it already exists. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".position").on('input', function() {
    var $option = $(`#dropdown_change option[data-pos="${this.id}"]`);
    if (!$option.length)
      $option = $(`<option data-pos="${this.id}" />`);

    $option.text(this.value).val(this.value).appendTo('#dropdown_change');
  });
});
```

```css
.position {
  width: 665px;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Chairperson: <input name="Chairperson" id="chair" type="text" maxlength="50" class="position" /><br /> 
President: <input name="President" id="pres" type="text" maxlength="50" class="position" /><br /> 
VicePresident: <input name="VicePresident" id="vice" type="text" maxlength="50" class="position" /><br />

<select id="dropdown_change">
  <option value="">Options here</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help